# UPS Class Files Location?

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8, shipping-methods

Where would the location of the UPS Shipping specific files be? I'm looking to extend some of the functionality for UPS and can't seem to find it.

Comment: The module you are looking for is `Mage_Usa`.

Comment: Thanks Oleskii. If you want to answer with `/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php` .. I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This file should not be edit directly. It should be extended through a module:

/Mage/Usa/Model/Shipping/Carrier/Ups.php